# Using D3 Force Directed Graph listening to events using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I plan to use D3 Force Directed Graph in my project. I was wondering if I can listen to click on the node. To show additional info about the node.

[D3 Force Directed Graph](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/force.html)

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like

```
node.on("click", function(d) {
    alert("You selected node "+ d);
});
```

should work.

For mouseover, something like

```
node.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    console.log("Moussed over node "+ d);
});
```